# How to Sum Record Broken Down by Month

Tags: t-sql

```
select p.productname, sum(e.dollars)
from product p with(nolock)
join exdata e with(nolock)
    on e.productid = p.productid
where e.createddt between '1 JUL 18' and '1 NOV 18'
group by p.productname
```

Have the above query. How would I go about breaking down the sum of dollars per month per productname? The [createddt] column is datetime. For example, lets say Clorox Wipes has a few records per month each with a dollar amount. I want to sum all the dollars for Clorox Wipes between those dates, while breaking each down by the month.

Comment: What Daniel posted below looks right to me. Note that, when using`NOLOCK` table hints SQL Server no longer guarantees that your query will return the correct results. This kind of thing can be a bummer come audit time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do:

```
select p.productname, mon = month(e.createddt), sum(e.dollars)
from product p with(nolock)
join exdata e with(nolock)
    on e.productid = p.productid
where e.createddt between '1 JUL 18' and '1 NOV 18'
group by p.productname, month(e.createddt)
```